# about decimal places

Tags: significant-figures

Suppose that $\tilde x$ is an approximation to x. Given that a necessary and
sufficient condition for $n$ correct decimal places in $\tilde x$ is
$|x − \tilde x| < 0.5 \times 10^{−n}$, so, how to derive a sufficient condition for $n$ correct significant figures in $\tilde x$, in which the upper bound on the relative error does not depend on $x$.

Comment: I don't really get what you are aiming for here. In particular what is the shape of the bound you would like to obtain?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Relative error is defined as error divided by the actual value.  If $x \approx 10^9$ you can get five significant figures with an absolute error of $5\cdot 10^4$.  If $x \approx 10^{-9}$ to get five significant figures you need an absolute error of $5 \cdot 10^{-14}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I will consider it any more.